# How to center a widget on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

A friend of mine asked me to help her center a Trip Adviser icon/widget on her Square Space site.  I'm sure this is a quick fix but it's been a while since I've done any webdesign work.  Ideas?

#### Here is a picture showing where the icon/widget is currently located on the site:

http://screencast.com/t/luITJ5i6l9N4

#### You can also view the site/page here:

http://www.thaxtonspeakeasy.com/contact/

#### This is the code she is using to generate the above:

```html
<div id="TA_rated86" class="TA_rated">
<ul id="oic9LYtuDaS" class="TA_links amswNN9">
<li id="t0leCBTSfd5y" class="BwqNAFQg">
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/badges/ollie-11424-2.gif" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=rated&amp;uniq=86&amp;locationId=3707749&amp;lang=en_US&amp;display_version=2"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
#CDSWIDFRR {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

(or `10px auto` seeing as how the element has a 10px margin on all sides now)

Comment: sounds good.  Are there any particular tags I need to place this in?

Comment: You'd place that in an existing CSS file, a new one, or in a `<style>` block in the page.